# Error message : Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value?

Tags: json, swift, uicollectionview, storyboard, uicollectionviewcell

I have been trying to populate data from a JSON file in a UICollectionView using a storyboard. After I created my outlets I connected my image and labels to my UICollectionViewCell.swift and my Collection View to UICollectionView. But, I am getting an error,

> Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file Music2/ViewController.swift, line 22.

Line 22 is below pointing to "collectionView.dataSoure = self

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.dataSource = self

    parseJson()

  }
```

After that, I parsed my JSON file and added a "DispatchQueue.main.async" at the end of pasreJson() (not sure about the part). Would this pose a problem?

//JSON

```
private func parseJson(){
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data (1)", ofType: "json") else {
        return
    }
   
    
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    do{
        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    let userData = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserData.self, from: jsonData)

        
        albums = userData.albums
        playlists = userData.playlists
        

    }catch{
        print("error : \(error)")
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
          }
       }
    }
```

Here is my complete View Controller :

```
   class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {


   @IBOutlet weak var collectionView : UICollectionView!


   //INSTANCE OF JSON DATA
   var albums = [Album]()
    var playlists = [Playlist]()

      override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.dataSource = self

    parseJson()

     }
    //UICollectionView protocols
      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection 
     section: Int) -> Int {

    return albums.count
     }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: 
     IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCell", 
    for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    
    cell.Label.text = albums[indexPath.row].title.capitalized
   
    return cell
    }



//JSON
    private func parseJson(){
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data (1)", ofType: "json") else {
        return
    }
   
    
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    do{
        let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    let userData = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserData.self, from: jsonData)

        
        albums = userData.albums
        playlists = userData.playlists
        

    }catch{
        print("error : \(error)")
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
          }
         }
      }
```

Comment: Again, why are you loading data under `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: can you explain this to me @el

Answer (score 0):

If you are crashing on the line `collectionView.dataSource = self` then you did not connect the collection view to the view controller in the storyboard. Open your storyboard and control-drag from the collection view to the view controller.